# jquery resizable canvas in a <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I use the resizable function of jquery (http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) for resize a div.
In this div I have an input and a canvas, I want that when I resize my div, the canvas follow, how can I do that ?

With a example code like this :

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
    });
</script>
<div id="resizable">
     <input type="text" id=field />
     <canvas id="mycanvas" height="400px"></canvas>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you make your `<canvas>` have a width and height of 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use CSS (like jQuery) then you must be sure to resize proportionally or the canvas drawings will appear distorted by stretching.  Do this by setting the aspectRatio property when applying .resizable().

Also since you want #myCanvas to also be resized, you must set the alsoResize property when applying .resizable().

```
  // make #resizable resizable
  // let #resizable know to also resize #myCanvas when it resizes
  // require that the resizing be proportional so the canvas drawing is not distorted

  $("#resizable").resizable({
    alsoResize: "#myCanvas",
    aspectRation:true
  }); 

  $("#myCanvas").resizable();
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your `canvas` element's `height` and `width` to 100%:

```css
div#resizable {
    height: 200px; /* Initial height. */
    width: 200px; /* Initial width. */
}

div#resizable canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: And what about the other child elements of `div`? They will overlap with a height of 100%

Comment: Not the best way since it allows the canvas to resize disproportionally and therefore appear distorted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $("#resizable").resizable({ stop: function(event, ui) {

            $("#mycanvas").attr({ width: ui.size.width, height: ui.size.height });

            // Adjusting the width or height attribute clears the canvas of
            // its contents, so you are forced to redraw.
            reDraw(this);

    } });
```

Comment: `#mycanvas` is an ID, meaning there will only ever be one matching element. No need to use `.each()` here: `$('#mycanvas').attr({ ... });`

Comment: Thank you, but where is your function reDraw ? It says me that it is not defined.

Comment: That is custom function.entire canvas drawing concepts will be there in redraw method.like that in your project surely one redraw function will be there to render the canvas.